# ARM Neon intrinsics, addition of two vectors

Tags: c, arm, addition, hpc, neon

I have a C function that is very simple, pairwise adds two arrays of ints:

```
void add_arrays(int* a, int* b, int* target, int size) {
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        target[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
}
```

I see that on ARM the Neon intrinsics are available in <arm_neon.h>, and you are supposed to be able to add, multiply, etc vectors, but all the examples I saw are super convoluted. Can somebody show how to perform something simple like pairwise addition using ARM Neon intrinsics?

**UPDATE**
My terminology is wrong, I am looking to implement element-wise addition.

Comment: It's not pairwise add what you need,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, as Jake mentioned, what this code does is **not** pairwise addition.  Pairwise addition would be adding adjacent pairs; something like

```c
void add_arrays(int* a, int* target, int size) {
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        target[i] = a[i * 2] + a[(i * 2) + 1];
    }
}
```

That can be done using NEON, but I'm going to assume your code is right but your terminology is wrong for the rest of this answer.  If that's reversed, this answer plus looking at the docs for `vpaddq_s32` (or maybe `vpaddl_s32`)  should get you most of the way there.

For simplicity, I'm going to assume that size is a multiple of 4 (since 4 32-bit elements = 1 128-bit vector), so:

```c
void add_arrays(int* a, int* b, int* target, int size) {
    for(int i=0; i<size; i+=4) {
        target[  i  ] = a[  i  ] + b[  i  ];
        target[i + 1] = a[i + 1] + b[i + 1];
        target[i + 2] = a[i + 2] + b[i + 2];
        target[i + 3] = a[i + 3] + b[i + 3];
    }
}
```

Now let's add some NEON intrinsics:

```c
#include <arm_neon.h>

void add_arrays(int* a, int* b, int* target, int size) {
    for(int i=0; i<size; i+=4) {
        /* Load data into NEON register */
        int32x4_t av = vld1q_s32(&(a[i]));
        int32x4_t bv = vld1q_s32(&(b[i]));

        /* Perform the addition */
        int32x4_t targetv = vaddq_s32(av, bv);

        /* Store the result */
        vst1q_s32(&(target[i]), targetv);
    }
}
```

That's it.  You can see the difference in generated code at https://godbolt.org/z/W6KPv186x.

Comment: Both of the functions in the example on the godbolt generates Neon intrinsic code. That is `add     v0.4s, v0.4s, v1.4s`. If the optimization flag will be set lower than 3 then only your example will have Neon registers used. It will get even more interesting if the function add_array() will be rewritten to have inner for loop with stride of 4. The code will be exactly the same as in your Neon version without using Neon intrinsic. Of course optimization 3 needs to be turned on: https://godbolt.org/z/P1n3638bY